# Yii2 text field ajax call on blur

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

In Yii 1 you could add an option to the textField so that when this field is blurred it would launch an ajax call:

```
echo $form->textField($model, 'field_name', [    
    'ajax' => [
        'type' => 'POST',
        'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('ajax/process-field'),
        'update' => '#Form_field',
        'data' => array('field' => 'js:this.value'),
        'success' => 'jsFunction'
    ]]);
```

Is there any way to do the same in Yii2? I've been looking around but couldn't find it.

Comment: It guess this is not possible. However, it's not difficult to do this in a registerJS call. But be careful with validation that may use also the blur event.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution:
In the model rule you can use the parameter **whenClient**:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //your rules here
            [['field_name'], 'string', 'max' => 6, 'whenClient'=>function(attribute, value){
                $.get('/ajax/process-field', {'field':value}, jsFunction);
            }],

        ];
    }
```

It is documented in the Yii 2 docs: [Conditional Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation)

I am not sure if it is the best way but it works.